# C# SQL bulk insert from excel into SQL Column mapping between Excel and DataTable

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to insert records into sql but I run into a problem when I try to map the columns between Excel and SQl table. If I take the mapping out, the insert works but data ends up in the wrong fields. The error given is that the data source does not contain the column specified even though it does? Any suggestions to why it is not recognizing the column headers in Excel.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4xpn.png)

```
protected void LoadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            //Upload and save the file
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(path);

            string conString = string.Empty;
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

            switch (extension)
            {
                case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                    conString = ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + "; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"");
                    break;
                case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
                    conString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= "+ path +";Extended Properties ='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';");
                    break;
                    //conString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + "; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");
            }
            conString = string.Format(conString, path);
            using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
            {


                excel_con.Open();
               string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

                OleDbConnection OleDbcon = new OleDbConnection(conString);

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", OleDbcon);



                OleDbcon.Open();
                cmd.Connection = OleDbcon;
                objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                objAdapter1.Fill(ds);
                dtExcelData = ds.Tables[0];
                excel_con.Close();


                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
                {
                    using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                    {
                        //Set the database table name
                        sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.mytable";

                        //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Tag","Tag");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ExitDate","ExitDate");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Exit","Exit");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Amount","Amount");
                        con.Open();
                        sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }`
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: How far have you gone in your debugging efforts? When I create a spreadsheet with your data, and use this code, and set a breakpoint to review dtExcelData, I can drill into the ColumnNames and see each one like you say. Can you verify that you can do (or have already done) this inside of this code?

Comment: Can you supply schema of your table you are inserting into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your image it appears that your column headings in the excel are not flush left (which could indicate spaces). The Exit an Amount columns look like they have spaces at the start of them, which would break the mappings. I have tried your code and it seems to be working.

For the SQL bulk copy mappings the source column must match exactly the column name in the excel, and the destination column must match exactly the column name in the SQL table you are inserting into.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right. I Totally over looked it, There was a double space at beginning of each column heading in my  excel sheet. thanks again